# Forcing argparse to take everything as one input

Tags: python, argparse

Is there any way to make `argparse` pass several arguments as one? That is, I would like

```
foo bar baz
```

to make `argparse` pass

```
"bar baz"
```

as the argument.

Comment: Do you mean `--foo bar baz`?  Otherwise, how is `argparse` supposed to distinguish between `foo` and `bar` -- Unless you want to use subparsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes using `nargs="+"` will allow you to send in an arbitrary number of arguments.

You will receive them as a python list though.

Like this:-

```
parser.add_argument("foo", help="Give me an arbitrary number of arguments", nargs="+")
```

Comment: You also can use constant ONE_OR_MORE like this:

 parser.add_argument("foo", help="Give me an arbitrary number of arguments", nargs=argparse.ONE_OR_MORE)